# is there any DECODE-like function in Pig?

Tags: apache-pig

I need to replace text (month name) into another string (month number)
Is there any DECODE-like function that allows to replace one text into another?

I need something like oracle decode:

```
DECODE(inputStrint,'textToReplace1','Replacement1','textToReplace2,'Replacement2',etc);
```

Regards 
Pawel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You want to change the string value of a certain variable (let's say Month) by another string value ?**

- Since you use date you could check if there is any function which could help you here:

  [[http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions][1]](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#datetime-functions%5d%5b1%5d)
- Or You can code your UDF fonction
- Or you can do it with something like this :

  ```
  res = foreach Data {
      NewMonth = (Month matches 'January'? '1' : (Month matches 'February'? '2':(...) ) )
  Generate ...,NewMonth AS Month, ... ;
  };
  ```

  But it's not very beautiful, I truly recommend you to write a UDF fonction and then just call it :

  ```
  res = foreach Data Generate ...,ChangeMonth(Month) AS Month,...;
  ```